# Python, sorting a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble sorting out a dictionary key/value. Basically, this is what I'm trying to achieve: (This works)

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict['pens'] = ['234sdf, gjjhj', 'asd123, fghtert', '652efg, vbn456h']
>>> dict['pens'] = sorted(dict['pens'])
>>> print('Sorted: ', dict['pens'])
Sorted:  ['234sdf, gjjhj', '652efg, vbn456h', 'asd123, fghtert']
```

Now in my actual script, I get an error:

```
>>> grpProfile['students'] = sorted(grpProfile['students'])
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
type(grpProfile['students']) # returns list
type(grpProfile['students'][0] )# returns string
```

This also displays the list of strings.

```
for s in grpProfile['students']:
  print(s)
```

What could be wrong with my code? I'm completely lost. Every test I've done is working.

Comment: The one line of code you posted looks fine. Hard to say much else without a [mcve].

Comment: You are using Python 3 and have `None` values in your actual list. Python 3 has strict rules about which types can be compared.

Comment: Yeah it's the None. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ajcr has correctly pointed out, it seems that at least one element in your list is `NoneType()` type, i.e. you have a `None` object (maybe a variable you have not set).

Get rid of them, and then sort your list of values. To create a list without instances of that type:

```
[x for x in list if x is not None]
```

Comment: Yeah it's the None. Thank you very much